# How to get the stack to work in function calls?

Tags: c++

Does stack come into the frame in the following code? If num=5. Why am i getting the output as zero..what about the numbers from 5 to 1?

```
void rec(int num)
{
    cout << num << endl;
    if( num > 0 )
         return rec(num-1);
    cout << "after" << num << endl;
}
```

does it include the concept of stack?

Comment: You can try to debug the example by putting some breakpoints.

Comment: What do you mean, you get the output as zero? `rec(n)` should print all numbers from n down to 0, followed by "after0". If that's not happening for you, something very strange is going on.

Answer (score 1):

> "Why am i getting the output as zero"

Look at the logic of you function. `if(num>0)` - `return rec(num-1);`.
So for every nubmer above `0`, the function will just call itself again with `num-1`.
And only when `num==0` you will get to this line

```
cout<<"after"<<num<<endl;
```

Meaning that for every number you will enter, the function will do nothing and call itself again with  `number-1` **before** the `cout<<"after"<<num<<endl;` line, and at the last time it will not call it self again (since `num > 0` condition is false) and it will print `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the "returned value", you could do something like this:

```
void rec(int num)
{
    cout << num << endl;
    if( num > 0 )
         rec(num-1);
    cout << "after" << num << endl;
}
```

The `return rec(num-1);` is technically valid, but since the function doesn't actually return soemthing, it's the same as writing:

```
if (num > 0) 
{
    rec(num-1);
    return;
}
```